# When is Session_End() called in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, session-state, session-timeout

I have configured my `Web.Config` file as follow in a ASP.NET MVC 2 project:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1"/>
```

And added the following in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Session_End");
}

protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Session_Start");
}
```

`Session_Start()` is called when a new user goes on the website. I would have expected `Session_End()` to be called after 1 minute of idle time, but it's not the case. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be patient. The event should be called, but not necessarily right after the timeout.

You could try from a Browser: Start a session,wait > 1 minute, do a Postback somehow

This should help to verify that the Timeout works and I think you will also see the SessionEnd happening at that time. Otherwise, just wait and start some other sessions. The system will come around o calling it sometime.

Comment: Interesting, I would have figured it'd call it right at the 1 minute mark

Answer (score 13):

Remember this:

> If you don't save anything into the session, the session_end will not
>   fire. If you're saving data in the session in the first request, and calling abandon in the
>   same request the session_end will also not fired.
>
> Hope this helps!
>
> T

btw:
[ASP.NET Session_End event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777004/asp-net-session-end-event-not-firing/15777456#15777456)

Answer (score 3):

**Tip for testing:** Use `Session.Abandon` so you don't have to mess with your actual web.config value. Just don't set a session value and call `Session.Abandon` during the same request or it won't get stored.