# how to detect MVC 4 session end

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, logging, session-timeout, sessionend

I'm developing my web application using MVC 4, I need to send an email to the user after session time out or after session has been ended by the user. Anyone have any idea how to detect the session end? Thanks

Comment: which sessionstate mode are you using ?

Comment: @frebinfrancis I'm using InProc mode

Answer (score 1):

You can use Session_End Event in Global.asax File

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Write your Logic
        }
```

Be patient. The event should be called, but not necessarily right after the timeout.

You could try from a Browser: Start a session,wait > 1 minute, do a Postback somehow

This should help to verify that the Timeout works and I think you will also see the SessionEnd happening at that time. Otherwise, just wait and start some other sessions. The system will come around o calling it sometime.

[For more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373209/when-is-session-end-called-in-asp-net-mvc)

[About Session_End Event in MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2011/06/03/session-onend-or-session-end-won-t-fire-if-you-store-asp-net-sessions-out-of-proc.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: As far as I know, Session_End does not worked when the user close the browser, It's just working on case of timeout.

Comment: for that you have to track window unload event in jquery.

Comment: you can refer this question for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219970/img-requests-before-windows-close/28403618#28403618